# Can you get object from instantiation within a Task in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, object

I am trying to get the object from its instantiation within a `Task`. Is it possible to get the instantiated object as shown in this line of code, which is not correct:  `Object obj = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Object(pin, name));`. Here is the code:

```
List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();

for(int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
    {
         Object obj = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Object()); //incorrect line, to demonstrate what I wish to achieve
         objList.Add(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a noncence for me but `Object obj = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Object())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have `Task<Object>` in result, if you want object you have to add `.Result` , (but dont wait the result!)

```
var obj = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Object()).Result;
```

or add `await` (better)

```
var obj = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Object());
```

Comment: Please don't actually do this in real code.